# ESPN API, results of College Football teams not showing all teams

Tags: espn

A question for the **ESPN API team**...

I'm using the ESPN API, and when I use the `Teams API` to pull a list of College Football teams:

- I don't get a full list of all NCAA Football Teams
- I can't tell what    the reasoning of the teams that ARE listed is 
  (i.e. 1st result is `id:2`, 2nd result is `id:5`)

Is there a reason only some Teams show up?  And for the teams that DO show up, what is the rhyme or reason to them being the ones that have been selected to show up?

Thanks for the help!  I can add additional info or screenshots if needed at all-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The teams API uses pagination based on the resultLimit, resultOffset and resultCount nodes in the API response.  You can use the offset and limit GET parameters to get a larger, smaller result set as well as use them to make multiple requests in order to get all the teams in multiple requests.

For example: try setting limit to something larger than the default of 50.

Answer (score 2):

If you set the limit to -1, you get all of the teams.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rachel!  Very helpful-